# Can $3$ primes exist such that $3$ infinite sequences of natural numbers $X_i, Y_i, Z_i$ satisfy $p^{X_i} + q^{Y_i} = r^{Z_i}$ exist for all $i$?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

The longest sequence I found is $(1,1,1), (4,2,2)$ (the primes are $2,3$ and $5$)

Obviously one of the primes has to be $2$.

To be clear, all $3$ primes are different from each other.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos, I have done the editing.

Comment: Exponential diophantine equations have the habit of having only finitely many solutions.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you would also like these infinite sequences of natural numbers to be distinct, otherwise we can take any solution and repeat it infinitely which is boring.

Let's suppose there's an infinite sequence of distinct triples $(x_i,y_i,z_i)$ for $(p,q,r)$ that satisfy $p^{x_i}+q^{y_i}=r^{z_i}$.

At first glance, I don't see a way to approach this with algebraic number theory since the exponents vary nor do I see a way to approach this with p-adic number theory since it doesn't seem simple to rule out some convergent sequences in the p-adic integers in general, but I could easily be wrong I haven't thought it through. This is all just my way of saying I would like to jump to assuming the abc conjecture for the purposes of solving this problem.

The abc conjecture states for any $\varepsilon > 0$ there are only finitely many triples of coprime integers that satisfy $a+b=c$ and $c > \mathrm{rad}(abc)^{1+\varepsilon}$.

Since our choice of $a=p^{x_i}$, $b=q^{y_i}$, $c=r^{z_i}$ satisfies this, we can fix some $\varepsilon$ and we should only have finitely many cases where:

$$r^{z_i} > (pqr)^{1+\varepsilon}$$

However if we have infinitely many solutions, $z_i \to \infty$ as $i\to \infty$ because if it were bounded, $p^{x_i}+q^{y_i}$ would be bounded, which can not happen since there are infinitely many distinct solutions.

So there must be finitely many solutions.